# how to specify the collection in mongoengine?

Tags: python, pymongo, mongoengine

Hello community,

I want to insert a mongoengine document to specific collection.

I know there is the save method on the document. However this requires to use the connect method from mongoengine which I don't want to use. I need to pass in the collection and save the document to the specified collection. Below is some example code which illustrates my problem.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

```
from mongoengine import Document, StringField
from pymongo import MongoClient
from pymongo.collection import Collection

#  document which must be stored in measurements collection
class Example(Document):
    value = StringField()


def insert(value: str, collection: Collection):
    # create document
    example = Example(value=value)
    # TODO: insert document in specified collection


# conenct to db
client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/')
db = client.test
collection: Collection = db["measurements"]

# insert document to collection
insert(value="123", collection=collection)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend you to build a complex application on this pattern (mixing Mongoengine and pymongo) but to answer your question, you can achieve what you want with:

```
def insert(value: str, collection: Collection):
    example = Example(value=value)
    bson_data = example.to_mongo()
    collection.insert_one(bson_data)
```